# Make sure the SQLite on Android uses UTF-8 as a charset

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an Android application using SQLite as backend.

I want to make sure all the tables in the database use UTF-8. How can I achieve that?

I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (_all_columns_definitions_) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

but a syntax error arose.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given that sqlite only supports UTF-8 and UTF-16 as the encodings, you would have noticed if Android would create databases in something other than UTF-8. [sqlite3_open](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) defaults to create the database in UTF-8, and that is what Android is likely to use.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make use of the [`encoding PRAGMA`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding):

```
PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";
```

Comment: It still gives me this error: E/Database( 1776): Failure 1 (near "PRAGMA": syntax error) on 0x217230 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE list (id integer primary key, name text not null, sort_order integer not null, is_header integer(1) not null) PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";'

Comment: I think the previous error is because you can't use the PRAGMA statement while creating a table; you have to use while creating the database. The problem is that I don't create the database, Android does under the hood. So how can I tell Android to create the database setting UTF-8

Comment: Another question. What is the default charset for Android and SQLite? Maybe it is already UTF-8, and that would explain why I haven't found a lots of information on the topic on the Internet.

Comment: @dan: In SQLite `PRAGMA` is an SQL statement just by itself, you shouldn't join it with a `CREATE TABLE` statement, just execute the above query before any other query and you should be fine. On a second though, I'm not sure if you can change the charset on the fly... =\

Comment: @dan: Regarding the used charset you can see that by issuing the query `PRAGMA encoding;` and reading its results. I believe the default encoding is UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Answer (score 2):

By default Android SQLite uses UTF-8. 
I had the same problem with special characters, but because when I populated the database on the first launch I used a txt file with another charset.

Comment: If you populate some dafault or dummy data from within java class then make sure that this java class is UTF-8 encoded.