# How can i use Unicode characters such as Germanic umlaut in an sqlite database?

Tags: database, sqlite

I would like to use "Ä, Ö and Ü" in my sqlite database but when I use the snippet of code below, I am unable to retrieve the accented characters.

I am accessing the database using android or via sqlite3

```
CREATE TABLE haltestellen (
id integer primary key autoincrement,
name varchar(64)
);

insert into haltestellen(name) values("Bärenhof");
```

Comment: How do you access the database? (Language? driver?)

Comment: Please show the code that you use to access the DB.

Comment: If one of the answers solves your question you could mark it as such, otherwise you might want to comment on it, so we can give better answers.

Answer (score 3):

Sqlite only supports UTF-8 and UTF-16 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276215/make-sure-the-sqlite-on-android-uses-utf-8-as-a-charset)) there should not be a problem with your charset.

I guess that the terminal or tool you use to make the queries just does not support UTF-8 (or doesn't have it enabled). Just use a terminal or tool that supports UTF-8 and you should be fine.

As you do not give any more information I assume that you use the windows terminal cmd.exe.
You could try what was suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how):

`chcp 65001`

Still, for a better suited answer you will have to provide more information about your setup, like what are you actually trying where.

Comment: I'm using SQLITE3 in Terminal on OSX. I've enabled umlauts in the terminal in general via this post: http://superuser.com/questions/403753/cannot-type-any-special-character-or-umlaut-in-terminal. However, when I go into sqlite, it still won't accept special characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE haltestellen (
id integer primary key autoincrement,
name varchar(64) charset utf8
);

insert into haltestellen(name) values("Bärenhof");
```

If this doesn't work, you should show the code you use and make sure that everything is using utf8